# Is it possible to install lumen or laravel only in a sub directory

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have an existing website\application. I want to create a JSON API using lumen in a sub directory–something like `/api/`.

How do you install lumen or laravel only in a sub directory of a website?

Comment: Is your site is using any other framework ?

Comment: No just a custom application. I cannot install a framework in the root of the site because I don't want to break any existing functionality.

Comment: By the way, I tried installing lumen and creating a symbolic link to the public folder to an `/api/` folder in the site but it did not appear to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using Alias in your apache conf (virtualhost):

```
Alias /api /path/to/api/public
<Directory /path/to/api/public>
    Allowoverride All 
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Also, because Lumen gets the wrong path when used from a sub directory you will need to change the following line in Lumens public/index.php:
from `$app->run();` to `$app->run($app->make('request'));`

Comment: This didn't actually solve my problem, but brought me to a solution. I was using nginx in my dev environment, so the redirects in my `.htaccess` were not working. It was of those moments where I realized I wasted about two hours on something I should have figured out in 2 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

redirect request with ".htaccess" (if you cannot modify apache conf):

```
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/public/$1 [L]
```

use a Group with a prefix in your app/Http/router.php to remove the subfolder:

```
$app->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($app) {
  $app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
      return $app->version();
  });
});
```